# When to use a pointer to another struct in nested structs in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I'm confused as when should I use a pointer to another struct or contain a copy. For instance, should I use `Products *prods;` or `Products prods;` within Inventory? and how do I `malloc`?

```
typedef struct Products Products;
struct Products
{
    int  id;
    char *cat;
    char *name
};

typedef struct Inventory Inventory;
struct Inventory
{
    char* currency;
    int size;
    Products prods; // or Products *prods;
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Complementing Kyle's answer, the decision about whether or not using a pointer to `Products`, you must think of the following:

If you don't know how many elements you'll have, your `Inventory` struct should have at least:

```
typedef struct Inventory Inventory;
struct Inventory
{
    char *currency;
    int size, count;
    Products* prods;
    ... // other elements you should need
};
```

and the pointer should be defined as (when instantiating an `Inventory` element):

```
...
Inventory inv;
inv.size = _total_elems_you_will_need_
inv.prods = (Products *)malloc(inv.size * sizeof(Products));
...
```

On the other hand, if that amount is always fixed, then you can define your struct `Inventory` with something like this (instead of the pointer defined above):

```
Products prods;      // if you'll need only one element.
Products prods[10];  // if you'll need only ten.
```

Comment: And if you use malloc, don't forget to do: `#include <stdlib.h>`, and also test if its result has been `NULL`

Comment: Thanks, one more question, so I don't need to malloc Inventory, only Products, is that right?

Comment: You should need to malloc Inventory in the same sense Products does: if you'll need more than one Inventory object. You may think of this as if they were arrays...

Answer (score 1):

You should use a pointer when the size of the array is unknown at compile time.  If you know each Inventory struct will contain exactly one Products struct or 10 or 100, then just declare `Products prods[100]`.  But if you're reading arbitrary records at runtime and can't know at compile time how many Products records an Inventory struct will contain, then use `Products *prods`.  You'll also need `size` and `count` struct elements to keep track of how much you've malloc'd or realloc'd and how much of that memory you've filled with Products structs.

Comment: Thanks, I'm wondering, wouldn't `count` and `size` be the same? I guess I'm not sure why I need count.

Comment: `->size` would be the size of the malloc'd space as measured in structs.  `->count` would be the amount of space used, starting at 0 and incremented as you read product records and filled the space.  When `->count` == `->size` you need to realloc the pointer to get more space.